# debugging OpenGL: is there toString() functionality for matrices and vectors (mat3, mat4, vec3 &c)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-3

I am debugging an OpenGL program:

Is there some kind of toString() functionality for matrices and vectors (mat3, mat4, vec3 &c)?

I'm trying to avoid constructing nested for-loops with cout or printf.

But if that's the only way to do this, I"d love to hear advice on best practices.  I'm pretty new to C++ and am interested to hear about it.

What would be really cool is output to a laTeX / ConTeXt logfile.

That leads to a more extended version of the question:  is there some reflection functionality for these objects?  I'd like to know if the particular matrix I'm interested in is specified column-major or row-major, what/where its parent class is, &c.

Comment: Did my answer help for the first part? the second part should be put in a new question and this one marked as correct if the provided answer is suitable.

Comment: "*I'd like to know if the particular matrix I'm interested in is specified column-major or row-major*" It's GLM: it's always column-major ordering, just like OpenGL takes them. And what do you plan to do with that information anyway? Same question goes for the whole "parent class" thing; why do you *need* to know? And what makes you think they have parent classes to begin with?

Comment: @NicolBolas He doesnt state that he is using glm. He could be using his own vector/matrix library

Comment: we're using GLM, but part of the code-base is not glm, or something.  A bit confusing.  This is all through the edX BerkeleyX class by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the ofstream << operator for your matrix/vector class and then inside format it the way you want i.e. output << "(" << vector.x << " ", " << vector.y << etc. Then in your main program you can simply do std::cout << myVector << std::endl;

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/

The link shows how it can be implemented

Comment: i was wondering if there is some native (already implemented) such functionality. modifying gl classes is wouldn't be a high priority right now.

Comment: @JoshuaCullick You don't need to modify any classes. The << operator can be a non-member function, overloaded to accept a parameter of your matrix type. It's really just a couple of stand-alone functions.

Comment: @JoshuaCullick: OpenGL doesn't *have* classes.